# Shorten URL codes using middlewares in Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

I still want my codes in public directory, and since I have to use the school's computer, I can't make the URL from `localhost` to something else.

*Example:* whenever I type URL for `href`, I have to put it like this. (larsamp is my project name, posts are the param)

```
<a href="/larsamp/public/about">About</a>
```

But I just want to type this instead

```
<a href="/about">About</a>
```

Here is the routing PHP:

```
Route::get('/about', 'PagesController@about');
```

I found some solutions, but they do not work.

1. Change public directory to shorten the public part: I have another directory called private to store many things else.
2. Create a global variable (i.e. $u) and put it in the layout directory: but I have many layouts.
3. Overload href or make a function inherit href and use it instead: my teacher said that will make my program too complex. Not good.

In conclusion, a way to shorten URL without making the program too complex and can be used on a school computer (no changing host.txt)

Comment: Might want to consider the Laravel url helper: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `url()` helper which returns a fully qualified url:

```html
<a href="{{ url('about') }}>About</a>
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-url

Alternatively there is also the `route()` helper:

```php
Route::get('/about', 'PagesController@about')->name('pages.about');
```

```html
<a href="{{ route('pages.about') }}>About</a>
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-route